# connect to DB using SSH java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jsch

I tried connect to Oracle DB in java but i faced error and i search many time i didn't find thing help me.

when i tried to connect using SQL developer its success.

so i tried write java code to access the DB its success connect to SSH but i faced error when reaches `conn = DriverManager.getConnection`:

> "java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Oracle Error ORA-12650"

This is my function

```
public static Connection sshTunel() {
        String sshHost = "sshHost";
        String sshuser = "sshUser";
        String SshKeyFilepath =
            "pathOfKey";
        Session session;
        int localPort = 22;
        String remoteHost = "HostIp";
        int remotePort = 1521;
        String usr = "DB user";
        String pwd = "DB pass";
        try {
            java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            session = jsch.getSession(sshuser, sshHost, 22);
            jsch.addIdentity(SshKeyFilepath, "ssh Pass");
            config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            config.put("Compression", "yes");
            config.put("ConnectionAttempts", "2");
            session.setConfig(config);
            session.connect();

            System.out.println("SSH Connected ...");

            int assinged_port =
                session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, remoteHost, remotePort);

            System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " +
                               remoteHost + ":" + remotePort);
            System.out.println("Port Forwarded ...");
            try {
                Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");

                conn =
DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@remoteHost:1521/SID",
                            "DB User", "DB Pass");
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Error in connection");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return conn;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you connecting to `remoteHost:1521` rather than `localhost:<assigned_port>`? I'm a bit confused that you say SQL Developer connects - is that directly or also via SSH?

Comment: If you want to tunnel the DB connection, you need to connect to Oracle using localhost and locally assigned port

Comment: Dears i tried DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:22/SID",
                            "DB User", "DB Pass")

DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8080/SID",
                            "DB User", "DB Pass")
the same error, please how i can handle this.

Comment: @AlexPoole What exactly assigned_port ? what is the local host should i pass it to int assinged_port =
                session.setPortForwardingL

Comment: `assigned_port` is the port number that was allocated; presumably the same as `localPort` if it succeeded - what does our output show it returned? Using 22 for `localPort` doesn't seem right as that's a reserved port (for SSH), so maybe that shows -1 or something, if it doesn't throw an exception. I'd suggest you use an unreserved port number, e.g. 61521, for `localPort`.

Comment: @AlexPoole when i added local port forward i added Host: host_IP and port 1521 so when i connect DB using this SSH its success connect on SQL developer, but when  added local port forward i added Host: localhost and port 1521 its success connected to SSH but when i connect DB using this SSH i faced an error "get minus one from read call".
So for that i used host_IP with port 1521 because its success connect to on SQL developer and for that i pass host_IP 1521 in my code.

Comment: Sorry, I can't follow that. If you connect to remoteHost:1521 then SSH isn't being used. If it's relevant, edit your question to add the SQL Developer connection details and how you set up SSH for that. For your Java code, I'm wondering if you might need to call `setPortForwardingL` *before* `connect`?

Comment: @AlexPoole Please find the photo for SSH in SQL developer 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3ePe.png
In Host = host_IP 
Port = 22
userName = SSH userName
in the second host i put also host_IP with port 1521

When i test this SSH its success connected, the i create new connection and i choose type ssh (The ssh that i created and testes success)

Comment: That doesn't really make sense; you ssh to localhost and tunnel to localhost, so you should be able to connect direct to 1521 without ssh. Anyway... if that works, then previous comments stand. The `localPort`, and then `assigned_port`, should not be 22, they should be a high number; and then you use that in the SQL\*Net URL. And you *might* need to do that before `connect`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SSH connection is to port 22. The local port for the tunnel should be a different, non-reserved port, e.g. 61521.

You then use the local address and port in the SQL*Net URL for the connection.

So showing only the relevant parts:

```
    int localPort = 61521;
    String remoteHost = "HostIp";
    int remotePort = 1521;
    ...
    try {
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        session = jsch.getSession(sshuser, sshHost, 22);
        ...
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect();

        System.out.println("SSH Connected ...");

        int assinged_port =
            session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, remoteHost, remotePort);

        System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " +
                           remoteHost + ":" + remotePort);

        try {
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource");

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                       "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:61521/service_name",
                       "DB User", "DB Pass");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ...
```

---

In your SQL Developer screen shot, I would expect the first Host value to be your remote host, i.e. whatever `"sshHost" actually is in your code; which SSH contacts on port 22. The second Host and Port values are how the database listener is reached *by* the SSH session, not by you. ('localhost' there is the remote server; what *it* sees as local host, and reaches on loopback address 127.0.0.1). WIth the radio button selections, that SSH connection is allocating its own local port, and connecting to that, and you don't really need to know what value that has.

In your code, this call:

```
jsch.getSession(sshuser, sshHost, 22);
```

this is the equivalent of the first Host and Port in the SQL Developer dialog. Again, `sshHost` is the value in that first Host box.

Then this call:

```
session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, remoteHost, remotePort);
```

is the equivalent to the second Host and Port section in your SQL Developer screenhot. Here, `remoteHost` is the Host value, probbaly `localhost`; and `remotePort` is Port value, which is 1521.

Where this differs from the SQL Developer set-up is the `localPort` value. In SQL Developer that is being auto-assigned (because you have 'automatically assign local port' selected). In your code you are specifying is yourself, and it's that value that has to be a non-reserved port.

So with just the relevant parts, you do something like:

```
jsch.getSession(sshuser, 'your_remote_host', 22);
session.connect();
session.setPortForwardingL(61521, 'localhost', 1521);
DriverManager.getConnection(
                   "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:61521/service_name"
```

It may be a bit confusing that there are two references to `localhost` and that they seem to mean slightly different things. That's because it's a special loopback address that stays within the computer (hence 'local'). You can think of the first one (in `setPortForwaringL`) as the remote server's internal reference to itself; and the second one (in the `getConnection()`) as your PC's internal reference to *itself*.

It's even more confusing that your screenshot shows `localhost` for both Host values. If that's what you really have then it doesn't make much sense and you shouldn't need SSH at all. So, I imagine you changed the real value to hide it for posting, and just picked a confusing fake value, instead of using `sshHost` or `hostIP` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, 
So you mean i should in SQL developer in local port forward fill host name: localhost and port for example 61521?

Comment: If SQL Developer works then don't change that. You *could* change to 'use specific local port` then then enter 61521 for that, just to test it. But (a) it isn't necessary, and (b) if you use that port number it will clash with your Java code - so leave it or revert it to 'automatically assign' or pick a different number. I've added some more explanation to my answer, hope that helps...

Comment: very thank for you support @Alex Poole, Please find img in my edited post, when i fill it like attached and test the connection SSH i get success test But when i created DB connection and choose the SSH that i created above i faced error "get minus one from read call" is it something that administrator should do or something from my side?

Comment: And  when i tried the code i get this error  : com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:61521 cannot be bound.

Comment: If you only test from SQL Developer but don't have an active connection, your Java code won't be able to use it; but you don't want it to. Make sure it is *not* connected if you're using the same port for both. With *only* your Java code running I don't see why that wouldn't work; but [based on this example](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/PortForwardingL.java.html) I've reverted the `connect` to before the port set-up - not sure if that was the latest issue.

Comment: is it possible that the issue is not from my side? for example the team infrastructure should do something like allow localhos with ip 61521  to connect to cloud DB?

Comment: Dear Alex,

Please check the second img that i added now above, its work on sql developer when i pass hos name in 2 filed the public ip, but how i can handle this through code?

Comment: The remote server and network don't know about 61521 That's the point of tunneling. I'm not convinced your second SQL Developer example works, if it's in the cloud and NAT's. Can you actually open a connection and run queries? Anyway, Java should work if you use the same values in the right places.

Comment: I am really confuse because the second img work in SQL developer and i access the DB and create table but in java the session.setPortForwardingL(localPort, remoteHost, remotePort); get error com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:1521 cannot be bound i put local port 1521 and host port 22 exactly like SQL developer.

I don't know why i am facing this error O-0 but very thank for your trying support me.

Comment: I guess it isn't NAT'd then. So `session.setPortForwardingL(61521, x.x.x.222, 1521)` - where x.x.x.222 is your remote host as entered in SQL Developer - should work too. Did you move that to before `connect`? And close the SQL Developer connection that uses the same local port?

Comment: Yes i move session.setPort before session.connect 
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: PortForwardingL: local port 127.0.0.1:61521 cannot be bound.

i faced this , i think there is something i didn't understood and very simple change will work :\

Comment: Woow its work now i change the jar of JDBC and its work with the same data that i entered in SQL developer Thank you for your support ALex